# Itextsharp Pdfwriter.getinstance returning 1kb pdf file

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to create a Memory stream that is a PDF, for testing I'm writing it to disk. When I write the stream I get a 1kb PDF file. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
It looks like I wasn't calling doc.close, however when I do it disposes of my finalreportstream. Is there a way around this?

```
public static Stream CombinePages(Stream firstPageStream, string nextPagesString)
    {


        var firstPage = new PdfReader(firstPageStream);
        var nextPages = new PdfReader(nextPagesString);

        Stream finalReportStream = new MemoryStream();
        var doc = new Document();
        var w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, finalReportStream);

            doc.Open();

            doc.SetPageSize(firstPage.GetPageSize(1));
            doc.NewPage();

            //Add Page 1
            w.DirectContent.AddTemplate(w.GetImportedPage(firstPage, 1), 0, 0);

            //Add the rest of the pages
            //copy readnextpages to doc starting page2 this cuts the first page
            for (var page = 2; page <= nextPages.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                doc.SetPageSize(nextPages.GetPageSize(page));

                doc.NewPage();
                w.DirectContent.AddTemplate(w.GetImportedPage(nextPages, page), 0, 0);
            }



        return finalReportStream;




    }
```

And then write it to disk:

```
        var fileStream = File.Create(destfilename);

        finalReportStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

        fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: The `PdfWriter` has a `CloseStream` property. Set it to `false` before closing: `w.CloseStream = false`.

Comment: A stream is an abstract wrapper around a concrete array of bytes. Unless you have 100% control over every aspect of the stream process (which you don't because you are using iText and the .Net runtime) you are just looking for trouble. I would recommend that once you are done with iText's portion that you call `ToArray()` on the stream and return that. Then whatever needs to consume that can either use those bytes directly or wrap them in a quick localized `MemoryStream`.